# PyMongo MongoDB - Long DB Query

Tags: python, regex, mongodb

I've got a fairly long MongoDB query which I have been using in the console:

```
db.addresses.find({ 
    $and: [ {"date": {$gte: "2017-06-01"}}, 
        {"date": {$lt: "2017-06-60"}}, 
        { $or: [{"address.postal_code" : { $regex: /^SW1 /i } }, 
            {"address.postal_code" : { $regex: /^SW2 /i } }, 
            {"address.postal_code" : { $regex: /^SW3 /i } }, 
            {"address.postal_code" : { $regex: /^SW4 /i } } 
        ]}
    ]})
```

I now need to use this in Python using PyMongo but am understandably getting a:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

As it's fairly complex, is there an easy way to escape it as I've got several to use, I've tried enclosing the above query like this:

```
"""The query from above between the brackets"""
addresses_to_process = db.addresses.find(query)
```

But I get an error:

```
TypeError: filter must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or other type that inherits from collections.Mapping
```

Comment: Why does everyone keep writing `$and`. ALL MongoDB query arguments are already AND conditions. You're dates are invalid, and "strings" which is not great. Did you even look at how to create a regular expression in python? Or did you just dump the code from the shell in blindly and expect it to work?

Comment: Also, Case insensitive searches with regular expressions require a "full collection scan" which you could easily avoid by simply providing each variant of "UPPERCASE" and "lowercase" remaining still anchored to the beginning of the string. That alone will make a "huge" difference, since it would then be possible to use an index to match instead.

Comment: OK so I'm new (less than a week) using MongoDB and appreciate I've got a lot to learn but I followed: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/ which explained AND.  Appreciate the dates are strings which I was aware but it was a simple solution to a problem today.  With regards to the case insensitive searches I am sure there are a million way my collection of docs could be better but to a noob you may as well be explaining the inner workings of a flux capacitor.  I'm happy to read.